# How to add only part name to list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}` for making a report.

The entire report is divided into two parts. Each part contains chapters. The sample index is as follows.

> List of Figures
>
> List of Tables
>
> Part I A
>
> Chapter 1
>
> 1.1
>
> Chapter 2
>
> 2.1
>
> Part II B
>
> Chapter 1
>
> 1.1
>
> Chapter 2
>
> 2.1

In the list of figures and list of tables portions, I want to add only the part name in as shown below.

> List of Figures
>
> Part I A
>
> 1.1 Caption of Figure
>
> 2.1 Caption of Figure
>
> Part II B
>
> 1.1 Caption of Figure
>
> 2.1 Caption of Figure

Please give me necessary solutions to do it.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. -  Related:[Splitting list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130203/124842)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

A patch answer by changing `\@part` a little bit and explicitly adding `\addcontentsline` with `lof` instead of `toc` again.

I have kept the vertical chapter gap in the `LoF` in order make the elements of figures origination from different chapters more outstanding.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
  \markboth{}{}% Find a hook in order to append content. 
}{%
  \markboth{}{}%
  \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>-2\relax
  \addcontentsline{lof}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
  \else
  \addcontentsline{lof}{part}{#1}%
  \fi
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\part{Number Three -- the Larch}



\chapter{A dummy chapter}
\begin{figure}

\caption{First figure}

\end{figure}


\begin{figure}

\caption{Second figure}

\end{figure}

\part{And now for something completely different}

\begin{figure}

\caption{Third figure}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52747/103046) to include the parts and not the chapters in the list of figures:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\thisparttitle{}
\def\thispartnumber{}
\newtoggle{noFigs}
\apptocmd{\@part}{\gdef\thisparttitle{#1}\gdef\thispartnumber{\thepart}\global\toggletrue{noFigs}}{}{}
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{%
  \iftoggle{noFigs}{
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\protect\numberline{\thispartnumber}{\thisparttitle}}{}{}}
    \global\togglefalse{noFigs}
  }{}
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\part{A}
\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Caption of first figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Caption of second figure}
\end{figure}

\part{B}
\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Caption of third figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Caption of fourth figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]