# Local toc displaying wrong items while using titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

For a bachelor thesis, I have a document with several 'phases' that each need their own local toc. I have used titletoc in order to do so, yet it does not give me a good result. I have used the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
\input{coverpage.tex}
\newpage
\input{Titlepage.tex}
\newpage
\input{Executive summary.tex}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\input{Main-introduction.tex}
\input{1PID/PID.tex}

\input{2Analysis/Analysis.tex}

\input{2Analysis/DesignDocument.tex}

\input{3Development/Development.tex}

\input{4Design/Design.tex}

\input{5Evaluation/Evaluation.tex}

\input{6Reflection/Reflection.tex}

\end{document}
```

In for instance the first chapter PID I have created a local toc the following way:

```
\begin{refsection}
\section*{Contents}
\startcontents[mytoc]
\printcontents[mytoc]{}{0}{}

\newpage

\section{Introduction}
\section{Project description}
\section{Problem description}
\section{Problem statement}
\section{Measurable goals}
\section{Communication objectives}
\newpage
\section{Time plan}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{refsection}
\stopcontents[mytoc]
```

Now for this local toc, I get the following displayed:
[image: Note the wrong input lines]

I do not understand the first and last lines. I would prefer for instance Chapter 1 as the first entry and I am completely lost as to why it displays chapter 2, which is not even written in this same .tex (since I have a separate .tex for each chapter). Note that I get this for each sequential local toc for every chapter.

Anyone that can help me out?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found answer in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/weird-behavior-of-partial-toc-with-titletoc) question previously posted. This issue can be solved by making sure the `\usepackage{hyperref}` is loaded after the `\usepackage{titletoc}`.